# Xml Serialize/Deserialize indexed entries

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-3, serialization, xsd

I have a xml file with indexed entries like:

```
<xml>
   <entry1>
   ...
   </entry1>
   <entry2>
   ...
   </entry2>
</xml>
```

I used xsd tool to generate the schema and then the c# classes and obviously it created:

```
public partial class entry1
...
public partial class entry2
```

How can i change the classes so that when i run serialize/deserialize it will recognize and name them as entry'n' both in the xml and in my objects?

I need to use infinite entries of the same type, and changing the xml is not possible.

Comment: Are there a finite number of entries possible?

Comment: Change your xml. `<entries><entry seq="1">...</entry><entry seq="2">...</entry></entries>`

Comment: Question is unclear. Do you want to merge classes `entry1` and `entry2` into a single class `entry` and use that single class to produce both XML elements `<entry1>` and `<entry2>`? And/or do you want to support any arbitrary number of `<entryN>` elements?

Comment: @MichaelGunter I need to use arbitrary <entryN> elements.

Comment: @L.B I cannot change the xml, i receive it like that.. api stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you cannot change the XML, you will not able able to use xsd.exe to produce classes for this XML. `XmlSerializer` has no built-in support for arbitrarily-named elements like `<entry1>`, `<entry2>`, ... `<entryN>`. You can either implement `IXmlSerializable` in your root class, thereby enabling `XmlSerializer` to call your custom (de)serialization code, or you can use `XmlDocument`, `XmlReader` or (my recommendation) `XDocument` to read the XML directly and, if you think it's necessary, construct an object model.

ASIDE: If at all possible, push back against this API. This violates good XML design. XML is by it's nature sequential. XML reading `<entry1/><entry2/>...<entryN/>` should really just be `<entry/><entry/>...<entry/>`. The position in the XML indicates the sequence.

EDIT: Based upon OPs comments, I'll add this. If your XML is truly large, performing a string replacement may not be the best solution. You can create a subclass of `XmlReader` that will replace the `<entryN>` elements with `<entry>` elements. You just need to override the `LocalName` property. Note that I haven't been very "safe" here -- any element or attribute that starts with "entry" will have its name changed to "entry". I will leave it to you to determine if this is sufficient for you. If not, it is certainly possible to perform additional state checks (e.g. make sure you're on an element) before replacing the name.

```
// This class implements the LocalName override
private class CustomXmlReader : CustomXmlReaderBase
{
    // constructor
    public CustomXmlReader(XmlReader inner)
        : base(inner)
    {
    }

    // LocalName override
    public override string LocalName
    {
        get { return base.LocalName.StartsWith("entry") ? "entry" : base.LocalName; }
    }
}

// This class implements base behavior for an XML reader that wraps another XML reader.
private abstract class CustomXmlReaderBase : XmlReader
{
    protected CustomXmlReaderBase(XmlReader inner)
    {
        _inner = inner;
    }

    private readonly XmlReader _inner;

    public override string GetAttribute(string name)
    {
        return _inner.GetAttribute(name);
    }

    public override string GetAttribute(string name, string namespaceURI)
    {
        return _inner.GetAttribute(name, namespaceURI);
    }

    public override string GetAttribute(int i)
    {
        return _inner.GetAttribute(i);
    }

    public override bool MoveToAttribute(string name)
    {
        return _inner.MoveToAttribute(name);
    }

    public override bool MoveToAttribute(string name, string ns)
    {
        return _inner.MoveToAttribute(name, ns);
    }

    public override bool MoveToFirstAttribute()
    {
        return _inner.MoveToFirstAttribute();
    }

    public override bool MoveToNextAttribute()
    {
        return _inner.MoveToNextAttribute();
    }

    public override bool MoveToElement()
    {
        return _inner.MoveToElement();
    }

    public override bool ReadAttributeValue()
    {
        return _inner.ReadAttributeValue();
    }

    public override bool Read()
    {
        return _inner.Read();
    }

    public override string LookupNamespace(string prefix)
    {
        return _inner.LookupNamespace(prefix);
    }

    public override void ResolveEntity()
    {
        _inner.ResolveEntity();
    }

    public override XmlNodeType NodeType
    {
        get { return _inner.NodeType; }
    }

    public override string LocalName
    {
        get { return _inner.LocalName; }
    }

    public override string NamespaceURI
    {
        get { return _inner.NamespaceURI; }
    }

    public override string Prefix
    {
        get { return _inner.Prefix; }
    }

    public override string Value
    {
        get { return _inner.Value; }
    }

    public override int Depth
    {
        get { return _inner.Depth; }
    }

    public override string BaseURI
    {
        get { return _inner.BaseURI; }
    }

    public override bool IsEmptyElement
    {
        get { return _inner.IsEmptyElement; }
    }

    public override int AttributeCount
    {
        get { return _inner.AttributeCount; }
    }

    public override bool EOF
    {
        get { return _inner.EOF; }
    }

    public override ReadState ReadState
    {
        get { return _inner.ReadState; }
    }

    public override XmlNameTable NameTable
    {
        get { return _inner.NameTable; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what i needed to know. I think it will be easier to just have a single class 'entry' and upon receiving the xml replace all the occurrences of string "entry1", "entry2".. by "entry", use XmlSerializer to being able to populate the objecs, and then repeat the string replace after writing the xml back.

It's a really big xml and I definitely DON'T want to have to build it piece by piece. Thank's a lot for your help!

And yes i do agree it really is a very bad practice, that's the very  first thing i thought.

Comment: Added some additional comments.